# Finding Total of Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-query-store

I have written this query to find total of sum of Net. But I am getting an error. Could you guys please help me?

```
SELECT SUM(net) AS net
FROM (select SUM(FB.[Net]) as net  FROM  (([table1 AS FB INNER JOIN
Date ON FB.DateKey =  Date.DateKey)
inner join [Store] on [Store].StoreKey = FB.StoreKey) WHERE (FullDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -12, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) 
AND DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
AND SName = 'XYZ'
AND DayNameOfWeek = 'Monday')
GROUP BY FB.[Net])
```

Kind Regards

Comment: lot of syntax errors..

Comment: you did not check any condition on this line `AND DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))`.

Comment: Hi Sachu, Could you point the syntax errors. I ran the code in sql server without using the first select sum statement and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting your code is key:

```
SELECT  SUM(net) AS net
FROM    (
            SELECT  SUM(FB.[Net]) as net  
            FROM    ((
                        [table1 AS FB 
                        INNER JOIN  Date 
                                ON  FB.DateKey =  Date.DateKey
                    )
                    inner join [Store] 
                            on [Store].StoreKey = FB.StoreKey
                    ) 
                    WHERE   (FullDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -12, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) 
                        AND DATEADD(day, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
                        AND SName = 'XYZ'
                        AND DayNameOfWeek = 'Monday')
                    GROUP BY FB.[Net]
                    )
```

I can see many errors now. I think this solves most syntax errors, but I'm not sure it gives the results you want:

```
SELECT  SUM(net) AS net
FROM    (
            SELECT  SUM([Net]) as net  
            FROM    (
                        SELECT      FB.net
                        FROM        table1 AS FB 
                        INNER JOIN  [Date] 
                                ON  FB.DateKey =  [Date].DateKey                    
                        inner join  [Store] 
                                on  [Store].StoreKey = FB.StoreKey                  
                        WHERE   FullDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -12, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
                            AND SName = 'XYZ'
                            AND DayNameOfWeek = 'Monday'
                        GROUP BY FB.[Net]
                    ) A
        ) B
```

**edit** That is your own code without syntax errors (far as I can tell). The following code should give the same result set:

```
SELECT      SUM(DISTINCT FB.net)
FROM        table1 AS FB 
INNER JOIN  [Date] 
        ON  FB.DateKey =  [Date].DateKey                    
INNER JOIN  [Store] 
        ON  [Store].StoreKey = FB.StoreKey                  
WHERE       FullDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -12, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
        AND SName = 'XYZ'
        AND DayNameOfWeek = 'Monday'
```

Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Did you try with last updated code (I removed a parenthesis)? Does it say which `)`?

Comment: @Shivang, also a tip, if you ask a question about a query which gives an error, ALWAYS include the error message in the question

Comment: Hi Honey,The code worked, thanks for your help (the first code which you posted also worked fine :) , apologies for not pasting it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, Removed unnecessary brackets and added proper alias. Please add alias to "Where" clause filter as well.

```
SELECT SUM(net) AS net
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(FB.[Net]) AS net
    FROM [table1] FB
    INNER JOIN [Date] D ON FB.DateKey = D.DateKey
    INNER JOIN [Store] S ON S.StoreKey = FB.StoreKey
    WHERE FullDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, - 12, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
            AND DATEADD(day, - 1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
        AND SName = 'XYZ'
        AND DayNameOfWeek = 'Monday'
    GROUP BY FB.[Net]
    ) t
```